# .NET Core 2.1 / Angular - SignalR takes exactly 2 minutes to connect to hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I have an Ionic app and I want it to connect to my socket. This worked in the SignalR preview just fine, and it essensialy still does, but it takes 2 minutes to connect for some reason...

[image]

I also get some errors when it connects:

[image]

This is my javascript code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
          .withUrl("http://192.168.178.11:8040/socket?sessionId=3dc1dc11")
          .build();

    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", message => {
      console.log(message);

      this.zone.run(() => {
        if(this.locked == true) {
          this.locked = false
        } else {
          this.locked = true;
        }
      });

      console.log(this.locked);
    });

    connection.start().catch(err => console.error);

}
```

This is my Hub:

```
public class DeviceHub : Hub
{
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var sessionId = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["sessionId"];

            return Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, sessionId);
        }
}
```

And this is my configuration in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<DeviceHub>("/socket");
});
```

Now my question is: How do I solve this?

**EDIT 1:**

The delay is before the `OnConnectedAsync()` method is invoked.

**EDIT 2:**

One more thing I think I should add is that it directly does a request to my API:

```
ws://192.168.178.11:8040/socket?sessionId=3dc1dc11&id=Pt-JDlSPq2_WEIl-8cdPZA
```

And that's the request that takes exactly two minutes to finish.

**EDIT 3:**

One more thing I would like to point out is that I am running a proxy. I cannot connect directy from my phone to the API, so I use a [proxy](https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy) for it. I have no idea if this has anything to do with it, but I just wanted to point it out just in case.

Comment: Can you check your `Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, sessionId)` isn't blocking?

Comment: Well, I have tried putting a breakpoint on it, but it only triggered after two minutes.

Comment: So you're saying the long delay is before your `OnConnectedAsync()` method is even invoked? If so, this is important information and should be added to your question.

Comment: @PaulTurner Yes it is, I've added it to the question.

Comment: It looks like your proxy might not support websockets and the detection of this is somehow causing the delay you're seeing.

Comment: @PaulTurner Okay, but why is it everytime **exactly** 120 seconds? I would assume there is some kind of delay/timer somewhere, but I have no idea where and why.

Comment: @PaulTurner Hmmmm.... You might be right. I tested it locally without the proxy and it worked just as I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well...

Shame on me.

The proxy caused the problem.

I have added bindings for my own IP in Visual Studio and it works now.

To do this open `\APPLICATION_FOLDER\.vs\config\applicationhost.config`.

Then look for `<bindings>` and add your own.

Example:

```
<bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:63251:localhost" />
  <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44333:localhost" />
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:63251:192.168.178.11" />
  <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44333:192.168.178.11" />
</bindings>
```

Save it, and you're done.

Note:

From now on you have to launch Visual Studio as administrator otherwise your application won't launch.